# Get Image Dimensions from external source

Tags: php, jquery, image

I have a page that loads content plus their image from an internal website but not not on the same sever as the script. The image is loaded dynamically `image.aspx?user=1234` which outputs the image.

Some people don't have an image so it puts a placeholder silhouette there which looks terrible.

I am trying to get the dimensions of the image to find out if it is the placeholder image so I can swap it with one that I made. I tried PHP's `getimagesize()` but it requires the file to be local.

Anyone have a solution for something like this?

Here is my code:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('http://internalSite.com/iwebimage.axd?qid='. $data->nomineeQID); 
                echo "Image width " .$width;
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "Image height " .$height;
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "Image type " .$type;
                echo "<BR>";
                echo "Attribute " .$attr;



Error:

Warning: getimagesize(http://internalSite.com/iwebimage.axd?qid=Q10090158): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\empower\submissions.php on line 220 Image width
Image height
Image type
Attribute
```

Comment: `getimagesize()` can support remote files

Comment: The error just says that you are unauthorized from accessing that image directly.

Comment: But I can access it directly by doing `<img src="http://internalSite.com/iwebimage.axd?qid=Q10090158">` ?

Comment: [This *might* help you](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10335514-RESOLVED-getimagesize()-on-remote-image-gives-401&p=10781697&viewfull=1#post10781697)

Comment: @scrowler: it'll work fine if allow_url_fopen is enabled. but it still downloads the entire image before trying to parse it, which is a major waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Yeah, the unfortunate pitfall of remote file size checks